# triple quotation marks

Tags: lua

How does

```
noremap  <S-CR> <Esc>:w<CR> :execute 'SlimeSend1 include("'.expand('%:p').'")'<CR>
```

translate to lua?
Here, triple quotation marks seem to be necessary.

Comment: write the whole thing in `lua.cmd[[<whole_thing>]]`.